# Xcode Archive Release Takes Around 2 hours

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild, xcode-archive

I am using Xcode 15.2 to archive my iOS app, it takes around 2 hours to complete the archive, during the first 15 minutes Xcode will be using huge CPU usage, then for the rest of the time until the archive completes the Xcode is using minimal CPU and memory usage.

During the last 1:30 h, Xcode will be compiling swift files, I do feel there is something wrong with Xcode or its configuration of the project.

[image]

**Here is an attached image of build settings:**

[image]

**Notes (I don't know if those effects the build time):**

1. We are using Swift Lint in the project.
2. We are using MVVM RXSwift Clean Architecture.

Comment: I have the same issue, but only with macOS release, not iOS nor visionOS. Any help?